# Unable to fetch element attribute when using sibling in xpath

Tags: xpath, automated-tests, appium

I'm using Appium in my mobile tests and I would like to get the text of the element. I'm able to get the element using `accessibility-id` and `xpath`. Here is the code used to get the element:

firstId= `'xpath', '//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name="5 Roles"]'`
or
secondId= `'accessibility_id', '5 Roles'`  or
thirdId = `'xpath', '//XCUIElementTypeProgressIndicator/following-sibling::XCUIElementTypeOther[1]'`

Then I'm trying to get the attribute of the element. My preference is to use the thirdId instead of the other two mentioned above. I'm using the following code to get attribute:

```
    def get_attribute_element(self, element):
        el = self.get_element(element)
        el_value = el.get_attribute('label')
        return el_value
```

When using the firstId and secondId the code successfully fetches the attribute and my tests pass but when using the thirdId, my tests fails as the `el_value=None` . I have no idea why it returns `None` when the id uses sibling. I checked the thirdId in Appium inspector and it correctly identifies the element in the app and it's a unique id too.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the problem. The element `'xpath', '//XCUIElementTypeProgressIndicator/following-sibling::XCUIElementTypeOther[1]'` is fine when looked from the Appium inspector but it has a child element which has the attribute I would like to fetch. So I just needed the child object of this element:

```
'xpath', '//XCUIElementTypeProgressIndicator/following-sibling::XCUIElementTypeOther[1]/XCUIElementTypeStaticText'
```